# How to have a responsive rows of buttons without specifying button width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid, responsive

I have 8 buttons of varying width. I want them to line up on 2 rows, 4 buttons each. I want the cell width to follow the widest button. I dont want the width of the button to grow based on window's width, but only enough to follow the widest button content only.

[image]

As seen here, all the cells follow the first button as it is the longest button. I am having difficulties to make this responsive.

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  width: fit-content;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
  background: yellow;
}
.text-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

button {
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  font-size:1rem;
}
```

As seen in the code, its 4 items on each row, but not sure how to make it less than that if window is resized. I've read about auto-fit and minmax but I am not able to specify the button width in px. I've tried flex but the other buttons won't follow the widest button's width.

[image]

You can try the codesandbox: https://codepen.io/hahahihi/pen/wvpBMqR. Thanks

Comment: What is limiting the width of the widest button, how does it decide to break over a few lines or not?

Comment: I guess you have to change the item repeat of grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); to fit the widths you want to use in your media queries.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below is almost equals to your grid example. The differences are `width: 100%` on the container, so the content fill the page width and the media query that shows the result on 2 or 4 columns depending on the screen width (run it full screen and resize the window below 480px to see the difference).

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}

.text-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

button {
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>
    <div class="text-container">
      <span>This is a button</span>
      <span>This is desc hahaha</span>
    </div>
   </button>
  <button>
    <div class="text-container">
      <span>This is a button</span>
      <span>This is desc</span>
    </div>
   </button>
  <button>
    <div class="text-container">
      <span>This is a button</span>
      <span>This is desc</span>
    </div>
   </button>
  <button>
    <div class="text-container">
      <span>This is a button</span>
      <span>This is desc</span>
    </div>
   </button>
  <button>
    <div class="text-container">
      <span>This is a button</span>
      <span>This is desc</span>
    </div>
   </button>
  <button>
    <div class="text-container">
      <span>This is a button</span>
      <span>This is desc</span>
    </div>
   </button>
  <button>
    <div class="text-container">
      <span>This is a button</span>
      <span>This is desc</span>
    </div>
   </button>
  <button>
    <div class="text-container">
      <span>This is a button</span>
      <span>This is desc</span>
    </div>
   </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tryed many times,use flex or grid or any else,I dont think css can do this XD;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).